# Create MMS alert to monitor primary availability

Tags: monitoring, mongodb

Is there a way in [MMS](https://mms.mongodb.com) to define an alert to monitor the case where none of the servers in a cluster get promoted to primary?

I tried defining the following alert: 'Alert if host of type primary is down', but the alarm doesn't get fired when I manually shutdown the servers in my cluster (to simulate a cluster going really bad).

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This doesn't exist at the moment in MMS, but it's scheduled for an upcoming MMS release (as always, the caveats about releases and schedules stand - nothing is guaranteed until you are using it).  The relevant feature requests are:

- https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/MMS-1235
- https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/MMS-1295